# How to recognize the type of data in C++?

Tags: c++

I learn C++ by a book, and always when I have a task to do, I'll add some of my features.
Now I wanted to add "check for dummy people", and if they write fractional number, not integer, the console will be closed.
I wanted to do like that:

```
cin >> timing;
if (timing == double) { 
    ...
```

But the Visual Studio compiler says `"type name is not allowed"`.

**Please, tell me how to do this check**

Comment: variables have static types. Therefore the shown code doesn't make sense and would never be necessary

Comment: What you probably want to do instead is read the input into a `std::string` then use one of the parsing functions (such as `std::stod` : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof) to check if you can convert the text into a `double`

Comment: Whatever book you're using it doesn't seem to to a very good job. [Here's a list of books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282) that are commonly recommended. If possible please invest in one or two of the beginners books from the list.

Comment: How to do string input I know. But what parsing functions do you mean? And I don't know any convert functions, 'cause I'm newbie( I hope you will answer in details. Anyway, thank you :)

Comment: You probably would have to make `timing` a std::string then write a function to check if the string looks like a double. This is not really a newbie type project. Wait till you learn more c++ before attempting.

Comment: I've already understood that, thanks) But what functions can we use for check?

Comment: Thank you, but your comment makes no sense. I asked about my problem and asked how to solve it, not about "I read this book - is it good or not?"

Answer (score 1):

The type of your `timing` variable is static, as are all types in C++. I'm going to assume it's an `std::string`. It will never be a `double` or an `int`. What you can do with it, is translate the information stored in it into another object of a different type.

For example, with `std::stod` you can try and convert the string into a `double`. This will return a `double` for all inputs, e.g. `"3.1"`, `"0"`, `"horse"`, or `""`. For the last two, however conversion will fail, and `std::stod` will throw.
However, the return value is *always* a `double`.

Now, you can check if the `double` holds an integral value. For instance you can convert the value to `long` and back and check if you get the same value. There are more sophisticated ways to check this, but it would be a good start.